# Extracting Data from Unstructured PDFs in Python

Tags: python, pdf

Like it says, I'm trying to find a method to extract data from PDFs in Python. I've explored a few solutions already, but I'm not finding any solution that fit the need.

The PDF I have is scanned in, but I can use Tesseract to turn it into a text pdf if necessary. The goal in the short term is to grab a few values from the PDF and store them. The large scale goal is to get a large number of these PDFs and perform this task automatically. I know how to store the data if I can get it out of the PDF, my problem is actually getting the values out.

I'm not at liberty to display the PDF, below is an example of what the document looks like.
[image: crude sketch of pdf layout]

Sorry for my crude art, I figured this would be easier than recreating an empty copy of the PDF, but I can make a better mock up if necessary. The fields I would like to extract are highlighted in red. Wherever it says TITLE: next to a field is where title would appear on the document, usually on a separate line, save for the field at the bottom.

I've tried using a few tools, notably Azure Cognitive Services and PyPDF2, however the issues I'm usually running into is that the output has each group of words as an individual line in the output, which does not work if the title of a form field is above it, like the example table below

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

The output returns left, then center, then right, then One, then Two, then Three. If the field for Two or One was left blank, searching for 3 rows below right would not give me the expected output.

I've run into a few other bugs with other solutions, like needing to have bounding boxes on my PDF for it to work, but I'm starting to run out of solutions to find, and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for how I can get this task done.

There are multiple pages, however I only really need 1-2, and I only have 1 scanned with Tesseract. The format stays relatively the same, although each pdf is independently scanned in so there could be minor changes there.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample, but with the text replaced with *Lorem ipsum* or something like that? Also, you said they weren't tabular, but then give an example table. Are they text combined with tables? If so, are the tables always in the same spot? Are these files multi-page or single?

Comment: @MattDMo would a picture of the layout suffice or should I try to make a PDF? I haven't been making any of these, I've just been getting them sent to me. I can sketch up a quick example of the layout quickly.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Please [edit] your question and put it there, along with the answers to my other questions above.

Comment: @MattDMo I made the requested edits, but just so they're also in here
The boxes are near each other, but the document isn't one neat table. In the table above, it's really 3 boxes, I just didn't know how best to denote the fact the titles were above the answers.

Comment: Have you tried importing the document into Excel? I think it's worth a try if you haven't.

Comment: @MattDMo I'll give it a shot and get back to you, I tried before and it didn't want to work.

Comment: @KJ In that case, ignoring Python and everything, how would you go about this task? I have a bunch of PDFs I need to get a specific value out of and put into a database. Let's say everything is on the table. Is there a tool that can do this? Besides manually doing this for each document. I'm currently trying with Python because I'm comfortable in it, but I'll learn C++ or Java if it's doable there.

Comment: Do you know how the PDFs were generated, and is there a chance you could access that software? One other approach is to go further up the chain and try to get the information in a more readable format, like Excel, JSON, or formatted text.

Comment: You say the documents are scanned. That means that the pdf essentially is a thin wrapped around a bitmap image. You should extract that bitmap image and apply bitmap based tools to it. Pdf based extraction tools usually assume non-scanned pdfs.

Comment: @MattDMo just an update, I've tried going up the chain, and it's apparently not an option.

Comment: @mkl I can look into this but I don't fully know what a thin or bitmap image are.

Comment: I actually meant a "thin wrapper around ...". Bitmap images are like PNGs or JPGs. In your case most likely the PDF mostly consists of a bitmap image that is shown on a PDF page.